# open3 popen3 binary data

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to send binary data through popen3, however I am getting an error.

The shell command I'm issuing is:

```
key = File.open('path.key').read
Open3.popen3("openssl pkcs8 -inform DER -outform PEM -passin pass:#{password}") do |stdin,  stdout, stderr|
  stdin.print(key)
  unless (err = stderr.read).empty? then raise err end
  stdout.read
end
```

where key is a binary file. OpenSSL says the key isn't valid, and I'm scratching my head.

Now, if I issue the command by having OpenSSL read it directly from the file system instead of passing it through the standard input it works correctly

```
"openssl pkcs8 -in path.key -inform DER -outform PEM -passin pass:#{password}"
```

Is there an encoding issue I'm not aware of? Or is this simply impossible. Since I will be receiving the keyfiles through a webservice, I would rather not have to save them to disk and have openssl read them, and instead do the whole process in memory.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Open3.popen3("openssl pkcs8 -inform DER ...") do |stdin,  stdout, stderr|
  stdin.reopen(File.open('path.key', 'rb'))
  unless (err = stderr.read).empty? then raise err end
  stdout.read
end
```

Instead of reading the file into a string, reopen the stdin of the process to be the file. Also, just to be on the safe side, open it in binary mode (notice the `rb` mode in the `File.open` call)